# Is an anonymous function required in an event callback?

Tags: javascript

Currently, my code works when I pass an anonymous function CONTAINING my custom method call into an event callback, but not when I try and call the custom method directly in the callback... IE:

```
var that = this;

// THIS WORKS:
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    that.onSlotRenderEnded(event);
});

// THIS DOES NOT. why? 
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', that.onSlotRenderEnded(event));
```

I'm trying to understand why my method call needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function before it'll work. I would like to be able to just shorten the code and call the custom method directly instead of through the anonymous.

Comment: you are calling your function, if you remove `(event)` from `that.onSlotRenderEnded(event)` it will work as intended

Comment: Javascript doesn't have call-by-name semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// THIS DOES NOT. why? 
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', that.onSlotRenderEnded(event));
```

In this case, your second argument is actually the result of calling `that.onSlotRenderEnded(event)` (probably not a function), that's why it doesn't work.

And no. It does **not require** it to be an anounymous function. Just a function.

People generally use them because those action functions (that will respond to events) are, more often than not, required only at that specific moment and nowhere else.

But, still, you could do:

```
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    that.onSlotRenderEnded(event);
});
```

or

```
function someName(event) {
    that.onSlotRenderEnded(event);
}
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', someName);
```

or

```
var someName = function (event) {
    that.onSlotRenderEnded(event);
}
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', someName);
```

Or, even, in this case, since all you do is delegate,

```
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', that.onSlotRenderEnded);
```

They all **should behave the same** * .

The only possible difference in them is the value of `this`, that can only be determined at the moment of the actual call. In this case, if you want to be sure of the value `this` will take, you can use either use the anonymous (and then not using the `this` reference, but some other variable, such as the `that` you are already using in the question), or you can resort to [`$.proxy()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), a utility function good for these situations, making it, in your case, something like:

```
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', $.proxy(that, 'onSlotRenderEnded'));
```

<sub>(* Of course, provided you do not have other variables with the `sameName` in the scope and so on.)</sub>

Comment: Excellent. Can't believe I was missing something so simple :-) I needed to modify the scope of `this` in the callback as well, so ultimately I did something like: `gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', $.proxy(that, 'onSlotRenderEnded'));` which appears to be working great.

Comment: Yes, right on. I was about to add a remark about `this`, but in the end thought it could complicate more than help. But... since your final solution ended up using `$.proxy()` I went ahead and added it so someone in the may benefit from it in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It does not need to be wrapped in an anonymous function. Rather, pass in the function definition without executing(*by having the parenthesis*) like

```
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', that.onSlotRenderEnded);
```

When passing in a callback, you have two options. Either you pass an anonymous function or you pass a function definition. In both cases, the `event` object will be automatically passed in as the first argument to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
gt.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', that.onSlotRenderEnded(event));
```

Here you just call method `that.onSlotRenderEnded` with undefined, as event is not defined. And the result of this method is passed to `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

By adding the brackets and passing event you are immediately calling your handler. Drop those and you should be ok.

So instead of

```
that.onSlotRenderEvent(event)
```

Just do

```
that.onSlotRenderEvent
```